# innerHTML wont add text to div

Tags: javascript, file

```
<html>
<body>
<div class = "container">
    <audio id="music" src="/music/orgmusic.mp3"type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
    <img id="titleimg"src = "images/titleimage.png">
        <div class = "gameContainer">
        </div>
        <div id ="play">Press Spacebar To Return To Main Menu!</div>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/setup.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/global.css">

<script src="/JS/setup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/JS/global.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS FILE:

```
document.getElementById("gameContainer").innerHTML = "hi this is words";
```

As you can see i have the in-line script set to insert text into my div called "gameContainer" but for some reason it doesn't work.

I know I can just type it in, but I wan't to get it to work through my JS file.
Any ideas on why the text won't insert?

Comment: Always check your browser console before asking why things aren't working. You have no such `#gameContainer` element

Comment: It should be `document.getElementsByClassName("gameContainer")[0]`

Answer (score 1):

You are do stuff based on Id and you set class in HTML.

```
<div class = "gameContainer"> // Hear you used class
</div>
```

In Js you used `document.getElementById("gameContainer").innerHTML`

```
<div id="gameContainer"> // Hear you have to used id instead of class
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
document.getElementById("gameContainer").innerHTML = "hi this is words";
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class = "container">
    <audio id="music" src="/music/orgmusic.mp3"type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
    <img id="titleimg"src = "images/titleimage.png">
        <div id = "gameContainer"class = "gameContainer">
        </div>
        
        <div id ="play">Press Spacebar To Return To Main Menu!</div>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/setup.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/global.css">

<script src="/JS/setup.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/JS/global.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```